# Cannot name a php $_SESSION the id value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I'm trying to make a voting system for a database currently records are rendered in php on screen with images for an up or down vote. When clicked they run the php scripts upvote.php or downvote.php respectively, they pass the id value (integer of the record being manipulated.

Currently it works, the scripts increment and decrement the records votes value as intended. I was, however, trying to stop a user doing this multiple times for one record. I was trying to achieve this by using a session and naming it the value of the id and before altering the votes value checking if the session for that id has been set.

I am going to use my 'upvote.php' as my example:

```
//Upvote Script

//begin session
session_start();

//database connection credentials import
include("../scripts/connection_variables.php");

//connect to mysql or display error
@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to the database, please try again shortly. If problem persists please refer to help then contact support.");

//select database or or display error
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("Could not connect to the database, please try again shortly. If problem persists please refer to help then contact support.");

//collect id
$id = $_GET['id'];

//check if user has already voted for this
if(isset($_SESSION[$id])) {
    //session has been set for this id, so don't execute the script
    exit();
}else{
    //set the session
    $_SESSION[$id] = "The punniest thing about puns is that they are really punny.";
    //increment the votes value
    $query = "UPDATE punniest_database SET votes= 1 + votes WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Even if you could make this work, a user need only clear cookies or just use a different browser to be able to vote again.

Comment: You need to check if the user has voted in the database, this means storing each vote being made.

Comment: I understand that the user would only have to do that, but I just want it for each session.

Comment: I also want them to be able to vote on more than just one record per session.

Comment: The "irony" of it all. Strange how someone downvoted your upvoting/downvoting question. (FYI: Wasn't me) ;-)

Comment: I know, I got that downvote about ten seconds after I posted the damm thing...

Comment: @gravysam You should consider using/adding a token, instead of only using sessions. Check this out http://phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Answer (score -1):

The default serializer used for sessions cannot handle numeric-only keys. It also emits a warning message during shutdown, you should see it in your logs (assuming you have logging enabled, look for Unknown).

> Older serialize handlers cannot store numeric index nor string index contains special characters

(quote from link below)

You can test it with the following script, save it somewhere and refresh a few times:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[time()] = true;
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

The most portable solution is prefixing the keys with a static string. Alternatively you can change the [serialize handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) used for sessions.

Comment: Thanks, that is some very useful information, when you say prefixing the keys with a static string are you saying to give each record a unique string?

Comment: I mean using keys like `"item-" . $id`

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain? A simple -1 doesn't leave room for improvement.